Size Mismatch Error When Loading State Dict for (Fine-tuned model)
I'm encountering a RuntimeError while trying to load a state_dict for LlamaForCausalLM. The error message indicates a size mismatch:
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for LlamaForCausalLM:
        size mismatch for model.embed_tokens.weight: copying a param with shape [128258, 4096] from checkpoint, the shape in current model is [128256, 4096].
        size mismatch for lm_head.weight: copying a param with shape [128258, 4096] from checkpoint, the shape in current model is [128256, 4096].


I'm trying to load a fine-tuned model loaded in huggingface (private) into a new instance of LlamaForCausalLM, but the shapes of the parameter vocab_size = 128258 in the checkpoint don't match the shapes expected by the Llama-3-8B-Instruct model which is vocab_size 128256 .
I'm expecting the state dict to load correctly without shape mismatches.
Steps I followed:

Fine-Tunning meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B with data
Merging with Meta-Llama-3-8B
Converting the Model to Llama.cpp GGUF
Quantizing the GGUF model
Using the Fine-Tuned Model to create an application

